# How to write javadoc links?

Tags: hyperlink, javadoc

How do I write links into javadocs?

Currently, I have something like:

```
{@link java.lang.Math#sqrt(double) Math.sqrt}
```

to produce the text `Math.sqrt` that should link to the `java.lang.Math.sqrt(double)` API, however, all it does is produce the text, no link.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get a link to something external to your code, you need use the `-linkoffline` option

where the `-linkoffline` option has the format something like this (artificially wrapped):

```
-linkoffline http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/
             http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/
```

This tells the JavaDoc tool where to find the link to the JavaDoc and for what packages to use that link.  From the 2nd URL, it will append "package-list" to load the actual URL:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/package-list

which you can verify by loading it in a browser does contain the list of packages documented at that JavaDoc URL.  This tells the JavaDoc tool that any `@link` references to anything in one of those packages should link to the provided URL.

Comment: Your exact answer doesn't work for me, but you gave me what I needed.

Comment: The link isn't malformed -- you can provide a string of text to be used as the link label as the second argument to @link.

Comment: @mipadi:  Oh!  In all my years of Java programming, I've never seen that.  Thanks for letting me know.  I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 21):

My answer is very much provided by Eddie, but his exact code doesn't work for me (or at least when using the version of javadoc that comes with Java 1.6)

If I do:

```
    javadoc -linkoffline http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/ 
                         http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/package-list
            -public FileName.java
```

then javadoc complains:

```
    javadoc: warning - Error fetching URL: 
    http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/package-list/package-list
```

If, on the other hand, I do:

```
    javadoc -linkoffline http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/ 
                         http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/ 
            -public FileName.java
```

Then it works, and my links are populated as I want them to be.

Additionally, my link isn't malformed. The text `{@link java.lang.Math#sqrt(double) Math.sqrt}` produces the link text `Math.sqrt` instead of the default `Math.sqrt(double)`.

Comment: As for the first variant (when you included *package-list* in the URL), the [javadoc documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#linkoffline) page says for the parameter *packagelistLoc* (quote): **Do not include the *package-list* filename.** So that pretty much explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for what you're trying to do, you can do this:

```
@see java.lang.Math#sqrt(double)
```

It doesn't give you the alternate text, but it gives you the link.

You can also write a more generic link like using standard html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

[This document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) might be of assistance, remember that for @link you need to use the URL for the doc you are linking to.

Comment: Link is dead. And that's why we don't post links on stackoverflow (or the stack exchange in general).