# How do I @link to a JSP file in javadoc?

Tags: java, jsp, javadoc

I get the following warning from javadoc:

```
warning - Tag @link:illegal character: "47"
```

when I have something like

```
/** 
 *  {@link /WebRoot/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/bob.jsp} for the template responsible
 */
```

in my code.

What is the best way to link to the jsp file in my javadoc comments?

Comment: This will help mb? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699771/how-to-write-javadoc-links

Answer (score 6):

have you tried using html-links in your JavaDoc? They do not need a @-Tag annotation.

```
/**
 *  <a href="./WebRoot/WEB-INF/tiles/templates/bob.jsp">click me</a>  
 */
```